# illegal variable name with csh and tcsh

Tags: csh, tcsh

Ubuntu 20.04 with update on about 1 May 2021.  NOT a linux expert.

in bash terminal,

% which csh

/usr/bin/csh

but when

% csh

illegal variable name.

same for tcsh.

Comment: Check your `~/.cshrc` and/or `~/.tcshrc` file(s)

Comment: Thanks!  a pkg, that was recently installed, added lines to the .cshrc file.